# PHP background script using ignore_abort_user() not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that takes the input and inserts it into the mysql database. As soon as the entry in the table is completed, this script calls another script using shell_exec(). Here is the first php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['post_arg'])){
    $theme = $_POST['topic_theme'];
    $des = $_POST['detail'];
    $hrs_to_go = 36;
    $t = time();

    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('topics');
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO `topics`.`theme`(heading, description, hrs_to_go, status, time) VALUES ('$theme', '$des', '$hrs_to_go', 'yes', '$t')";
    $ret_val = mysql_query($sql_query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `theme` where heading = '$theme'"));
    $themeID = $row['id'];
    shell_exec("php timer_script.php $themeID");
}
```

I want my second script to fetch the time and hrs_to_go from my table and update the field hrs_to_go accordingly.
But unfortunately the second script does not work properly and the browser keeps on loading without any redirect. Here is the second script:

```
session_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$interval = 20;
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('topics');
$sql_query_fectch = "SELECT time, hrs_to_go FROM `theme` WHERE id = '$argv[1]'";
$sql_query_update_status = "UPDATE `theme` SET status = 'no' WHERE id = '$argv[1]'";
$sql_query_update_hours = "UPDATE `theme` SET hrs_to_go = '$h_t_g' WHERE id = '$argv[1]'";
while (1) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql_query_fectch));
    $h_t_g = (time() - $row['time']) / 3600;
    $h_t_g = $row['hrs_to_go'] - $h_t_g;
    if($h_t_g == 0){

        /*set the status to not-active*/
        $result = mysql_query($sql_query_update_status, $conn);
        break;

    } else {
        /*Update the fiel hrs_to_go*/
        $result = mysql_query($sql_query_update_hours, $conn);
    }
    sleep($interval);
    unset($row);
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

Although my variables are hrs_togo but I've kept the iterval time smaller to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never ends.

This is because your update query doesn't automatically get updated with the new value for the variable $h_t_g. It gets set the first time and that's it.

Check this out, although I haven't checked if you have any other issues.

```
session_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$interval = 20;
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('topics');
$sql_query_fectch = "SELECT time, hrs_to_go FROM `theme` WHERE id = '$argv[1]'";
$sql_query_update_status = "UPDATE `theme` SET status = 'no' WHERE id = '$argv[1]'";

while (1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql_query_fectch));
    $h_t_g = (time() - $row['time']) / 3600;
    $h_t_g = $row['hrs_to_go'] - $h_t_g;
    if($h_t_g == 0){

        /*set the status to not-active*/
        $result = mysql_query($sql_query_update_status, $conn);
        break;

    } else {
        /*Update the fiel hrs_to_go*/
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `theme` SET hrs_to_go = '$h_t_g' WHERE id = '$argv[1]'", $conn);
    }
    sleep($interval);
    unset($row);
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But I tried it with no luck. The browser again keeps on loading. I think there might be some other issue with the script.

Comment: I am pretty sure your loop never breaks because $h_t_g never gets equal to 0. Just debug, set the while to loop just 10 times and var_dump all the variables and see what they output

Comment: You're right. The variable $h_t_g never gets changes.

Comment: The problem I find is that It displays `Notice: Undefined variable: argv in D:\xampp\htdocs\timer_script.php on line 9` and same errors many times. I cannot find what's wrong with argv?

Comment: Check the first script and see what `$theme` and `$themeID` output, it might be empty so no arguments get passed to the script. Also check to see what's in the database. You should also output `php_sapi_name()` in the second script and see if it returns `CLI` or you can also try `$_SERVER['argv']` instead of `$argv`

Comment: I tried what you said, but with the same results.  `php_sapi_name()` also returned `CLI`.

Comment: and what did `$themeID` in the first script return?

Comment: same id as from the databse

Comment: try to solve the issue with `$argv` first and then debug from there as i'm sure something else will fail. maybe some php config is preventing you from reading passed params